# How can I read CSV with strange quoting in ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have CSV file with some line like:

```
col1,col "two",col3
```

so i get `Illegal quoting` error and fix that by setting `:quote_char => "\x00"`

```
["col1", "col\"two\"", "col3"]
```

but there is a line like

```
col1,col2,"col,3"
```

later in that file

```
["col1", "col2", "\"col", "3\""]
```

then i read file line by line and call `parse_csv` wrapped in block. Set `:quote_char => "\""`, `rescue` `CSV::MalformedCSVError` exceptions and for that particular lines set `:quote_char => "\x00"` and `retry`

All works perfectly until we get line

```
col1,col "two","col,3"
```

in this case it `rescue`s from exception, set `:quote_char => "\x00"` and result is

```
["col1", "col\"two\"", "\"col", "3\""]
```

Apple Numbers is able to openn that file absolutely correctly.

Is there are any setting for `parse_csv` to handle this without preprocess string in some way?

**UPD** i show CSV lines as it is in file and results (arrays) as it was printed by `p`. there are no actual `\"` in my strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an invalid csv file. If you have access to the source, you could (ask to) generate the data as follows:

```
col1,"col ""two""","col,3"
```

If not, the only option is to parse the data yourself:

```
pseudocode:

while(read_line) {

    bool InsideQuotes = false
    for each_char_in_line {

        if(char == doublequote)
            InsideQuotes = !InsideQuotes 

        if(char == ',' and !InsideQuotes)
            // separator found - process field
    }
}
```

This will also take care of escaped quotes like in `col1,"col ""two""","col,3"`.

If the file contains multiline fields, some more work has to be done.

Comment: I have no access to the source unfortunately. I think such char by char processing will cause huge performance penalty. That part of code processing big CSV files (millions of records)

Comment: @Yaroslav Well, let's hope there are no fields like `,24" monitor,` in that file :)

Comment: @Yaroslav About performance: I don't know Ruby or it's performance, but I guess if the lines could be treated as arrays it wouldn't be that bad. The same algorithm in C/C++ is actually faster than a standard parser. Maybe you could check if Ruby supports memory mapped files, this would also eliminate the need for readline (which copies the string into a buffer).

Comment: @Yaroslav I had a quick look at the Ruby String class. While there is a `str[index]` which returns a 1 character string, I think `getbyte(index)` would be faster. This returns an integer and could be compared to 34 `"` or 44 `,`. You could do a quick performance test by counting the commas in each line in your current code for example. There's also `each_byte` and `each_char`.

Answer (score 1):

CSV is less a standard and more of a name that everyone thinks they're using to describe their quirky format correctly, and this is despite their being an [RFC standard for CSV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) which is just another thing nobody pays attention to.

As such, a lot of programs that read CSV are very forgiving. Ruby's core CSV library is pretty good, but not as adaptable as others. That's because you've got Ruby there to get you out of a jam, and in Numbers you don't.

Try rewriting `\"` to `""` which is conventional CSV formatting, as defined in the spec linked above:

```
CSV.parse(File.read.gsub(/\\"/, '""'))
```

Comment: Sorry for that inaccuracy but i show CSV lines as it is in file and results (arrays) as it was printed by `p`. there are no actual `\"` in my strings.